# Efficient Datomic query to perform filtering on paginated sets

Tags: clojure, datomic, datalog

Given that Datomic [does not support pagination](http://aan.io/datomic-pagination/) I'm wondering how to efficiently support a query such as:

> Take the first 30 entities on `:history/body`, find entities whose
>   `:history/body` matches some regex.

Here's how I'd do regex matching alone:

```clojure
{:find [?e]
 :where [[?e :history/body ?body]
         [(re-find #"foo.*bar$" ?body)]]}
```

Observations:

1. I could then `(take ...)` from those, but that is *not* the same as matching against the first 30 entities.
2. I could get *all* entities, `take 30` then manually filter with `re-find`, but if I have 30M entities, getting all of them just to `take 30` seems wildly inefficient. Additionally: what if I wanted to take 20M out of my 30M entities and filter them via `re-find`?

Datomic docs talk about how queries are executed locally, but I've tried doing in-memory transformations on a set of 52913 entities (granted, they're fully `touch`ed) and it takes ~5 seconds. Imagine how bad it'd be in the millions or 10s of millions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Just brainstorming, here)

First of all, if you're ever using regexp, you may want to consider a fulltext index on :history/body so that you can do:

```
[(fulltext $ :history/body "foo*bar") [[?e]]]
```

(Note: You can't change `:db/fulltext true/false` on an existing entity schema)

Sorting is something you have to do outside the query. But depending on your data, you may be able to constrain your query to a single "page" and then apply your predicate to just those entities.

For example, if we were only paginating `:history` entities by an auto-incrementing `:history/id`, then we'd know beforehand that "Page 3" is `:history/id` 61 to 90.

```
[:find ?e
 :in $ ?min-id ?max-id
 :where
 [?e :history/id ?id]
 (<= ?min-id ?id ?max-id)
 (fulltext $ :history/body "foo*bar") [[?e]]]
```

Maybe something like this:

```
(defn get-filtered-history-page [page-n match]
  (let [per-page 30
        min-id (inc (* (dec page-n) per-page))
        max-id (+ min-id per-page)]
    (d/q '[:find ?e
           :in $ ?min-id ?max-id ?match
           :where
           [?e :history/id ?id]
           [(<= ?min-id ?id ?max-id)]
           [(fulltext $ :history/body ?match) [[?e]]]]
      (get-db) min-id max-id match)))
```

But, of course, the problem is that constraining the paginated set is usually based on an ordering you don't know in advance, so this isn't very helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I'll work through this when I have a chance, looks like a good start.